# Retrieve data from array session to ajax script

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I'm developing an eCommerce in Laravel 5.4.
When the user press into "buy" button, i make a query with product  id hidden into a  input field.
Then, i have a Product collection and then, insert them into an session array.
This will be in future my buys cart

This is my controller method

```
 public function agregarACarrito(Request $request){

    $producto = new Producto();

    $producto=Producto::where('id','=',$request->parametros)
                        ->get();


   $request->session()->push('session_products',$producto);


    return json_encode($request->session()->get('session_products')) ;


}
```

And this is my AJAX script

```
function agregarACarrito(){

    var parametros =$("#id").val();



            $.ajax({
            data:{parametros:parametros},
            url:'/agregarACarrito',
            type:'post',
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
                for(var i in data) {    

                $('#session').html("<li>"+data[i].modelo+"</li>");

                }
            }
            });



}
```

The problem begins when i want to retrieve this array session into my view.
Or i get object], or [undefined], or just an error in console.

What im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, when i was retrieving the data to the view the array session of this type $request->session()->get('session_products'), i was sending a bidimensional array, where 'session_products' was on row 1,2,3,4 etc and column 0.